# is gradle memory increasing with amount of unit tests? (gradle 1.x)

Tags: gradle

Our unit test count has been increasing and gradle has now started running out of memory...

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> Java heap space
```

So we added gradle.properties with the jvm args -Xmx512m.  I am wondering why gradle uses more and more memory as we add unit tests.  Memory use should be constant, shouldn't it?

This is on the github project playorm found here https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm

Dean

Comment: I know little to nothing about Gradle internals, but since Gradle has to search for all tests during setup, it seems likely that there is a certain amount of static (and growig) use of memory before the tests are invoked in a different JVM.  Is it a *very* large number of tests and test classes?

Comment: It is now up to 110 tests.

Comment: that's not very many, IMO

Comment: exactly, so why did I start getting OOM as tests increased...it should stay pretty level.  I tweaked the gradle memory not the test VM memory so it appears gradle is increasing per test at a rate that is a bit higher than I would expect though maybe it is much like the ant/junit issue where the logs where in-memory until the test was done or something...not sure, something just feels off.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All Tests executed using the Gradle Test task are executed in a seperate jvm and not in the jvm, the gradle build is executed with. So changing values in gradle.properties does not solve your problem. To increase the memory of the Test - JVM you have to configure the Test task.

```
test{
     maxHeapSize = "512m"
}
```

hope that helped,

Answer to Dean's issue is in comments.

René

Comment: uhm, what I did fixed the issue otherwise I consistently got that error.  I did not try your fix since my fix worked.  I only have 110 tests so not sure why gradle has trouble though I seem to remember an issue with ant and storing logs in memory until the test is done and I wonder if it is related to that.

Comment: what gradle version do you use? in earlier gradle versions we had issues with tests that have a huge logging output and we kept this is memory. This was fixed in one of the recent gradle versions (can't remember the details)

Comment: hmmm, it appears this is 1.3.  The project is using a gradlew file with some kind of gradle wrapper which I thought always tried to retrieve the latest gradle or something but 1.3 is old, isn't it.

Comment: latest gradle version is 1.6 and 1.7 is near (rc1 has been released already). In short: The purpose of the gradle wrapper is to keep the information which gradle version to use in your build within your vcs and run it with the specified version by downloading it if necessary

Comment: is there a way to do the same thing in an android project that doesn't have the java plugin?

Comment: This worked for me on some monster tests. But where is this documented? I feel like SO needs an informal rule for Gradle questions where the official documentation must be referenced, if applicable. It would be better if people learn to find these things themselves rather than being dependent on asking someone. The docs do mention that "certain tasks" fork additional JVM processes, like tests, but doesn't seem to say how to configure those. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:configuring_jvm_memory

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same issue (huge memory usage when running tests with gradle). I am actually testing a custom plugin that is downloading pom and jar/war, and it seems the debug output logs pretty much the whole files downloaded content. And during the execution, I have the feeling all this logging is stored in memory. I am using Gradle 1.7 with Java 1.6.